# Json Array to ListBox - C#

Tags: c#, json, listbox

I have a JSON array of Timezones that I want to display in a list box.

JSON Structure:

```
 [
  {
    "value": "Dateline Standard Time",
    "abbr": "DST",
    "offset": -12,
    "isdst": false,
    "text": "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West"
  },
  {
    "value": "UTC-11",
    "abbr": "U",
    "offset": -11,
    "isdst": false,
    "text": "(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11"
  }
]
```

On the load of my application, I load the JSON results.

Loading JSON in Application:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadJson();
        }

        public void LoadJson()
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("timeZones.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();

                List<TimeZones> timeZones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TimeZones>>(json);
                listBox1.DataSource = timeZones;
            }
           }
        }

public class TimeZones
    {

        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Abbr { get; set; }
        public string Offset { get; set; }
        public string IsDst { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

When I add this list as the datasource to my listbox, I get the following, cow can I get each line to show  Value, Abbr, Offset isDst and Text? What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: You could override `ToString()` method of `TimeZones`

Comment: Im sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: By default, the type of an object is returned by `ToString()` (what you see in the listbox). If you override that method, you can display whatever you want (any combination of properties for example). See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to override `ToString()` method of `TimeZones` like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", 
                         Value, Abbr, Offset, IsDst, Text);
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx